# c++ glfw macosx dim screen vs f1

Tags: c++, glfw

I'm writing a GLFW app in C++ on MacOSX.

It runs in GLFW_FULLSCREEN mode

Now, when I press the "dim screen / f1" button, my Mac dims my screen.

I do not want that to happen. Instead, I want GLFW to receive a "key press F1" event (or a "key press blah blah blah" event. Is there a way to tell MacOSX to NOT interpret the "dim screen" and send it to my full-screened GLFW app?

Thanks!

PS: I have admin rights on the Mac and am willing to make changes to system to make this happen if necessary.

Comment: If you plan on using this software for yourself only, you can go to the Keyboards preference panel and check `Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys`. Otherwise, you'll have to figure a better solution. There has to be one.

Comment: @zneak this worked beautifully. If you repost your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `glfwDisable (GLFW_SYSTEM_KEYS);` then the keyboard events should be sent to your application.

Answer (score 0):

As I said, there has to be some better solution, especially if you want to redistribute your program, but if you plan on using this software for yourself only, you can go to the Keyboards preference panel and check Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys.